# Calling Wordpress rest api

Tags: wordpress, digital-ocean, wordpress-rest-api

I'm currently working on application where I want to use data from my blog which is hosted on digital ocean. I have installed wordpress for the blog on the server with domain name abc.com. I have to call wordpress rest api to get data without authentication if possible or using application client secret key. How we can do that?.

While calling like this "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/abc.com/posts/?pretty=true"

this return

```
{
"error": "unknown_blog",
"message": "Unknown blog"
}
```

Comment: That looks like a URL for wordpress.com, which is a commerical blog hosting service, and not a self-hosted WordPress installation.

Comment: @ChrisHerbert then how should I call rest api for wordpress on self hosted wordpress installation

Comment: The documentation is here: http://v2.wp-api.org

Comment: @ChrisHerbert calling by this results not showing attributes like detailed post like title, content etc

Comment: Calling what?  What URL did you use?

Comment: @sasuke Hi. Did you resolve it? What API did you end up using? I am confused about whether to use WP-API-V2 or WP.COM-API V1.1

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

do you mean

abc.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

url like this will get the all posts title content, and if you want to get single post, you can do

abc.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1

1 is post_id , you can replace with other post id

Answer (score 0):

Below function is useful for register endpoint for creating API from function.php file. Refer below link for further deployment.

```
    register_rest_route
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/

Below link is very helpful for create API in WP environment.

[http://v2.wp-api.org/](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/)

You can get overview from below word press popular plugin as well, but in latest word press there is no need to use this plugin as default word press provide almost all functionalities.

[WP REST API (WP API)](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)